# How can I manage sequence of DML operations in a trigger?

Tags: trigger

How can I manage sequence of DML operations in a trigger? Let’s say we have 3 objects, A, B & C. All have after triggers defined. Insert for B is present in “after insert” trigger of A and DML insert for C is present in “after insert” trigger of B. How to make sure that before inserting B, all A records are processed and before inserting C, all B records are inserted?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is very difficult at best, and impossible at worst.

Triggers are executed in chunks of up to 200 records. If you have more than 200 records, then you'd see the trigger for `A` run, then the trigger for `B` run, then the trigger for `C` run. After that, you'd see another execution sequence of A -> B -> C

Even the A -> B -> C order may not happen in that exact order. It depends on what other triggers, workflow field updates, process builder processes, etc... exist in your org.

If the relationship between `A` and `B` is master-detail, and you have a rollup summary field on `A` that aggregates data from `B`, an insert of `B` is very likely going to cause the trigger for `A` to fire again.

About the best you can hope for right now is that your triggers will execute in an orderly fashion. To that end, the trigger best practices should be followed:

- One Trigger per SObject
- Use a trigger framework to get the logic outside of the trigger itself
- Copious unit testing, and integration testing to make sure your individual components are behaving, and interact with each other as expected

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that's the best explanation I could hope for.